# Need to replace tire on Dahon folding bike

Tags: tire

I bought a Dahon Vitesse D8 two years ago and it's lasted extremely well so far. Recently, the rear tire got a puncture and as my tires both looked pretty worn, I thought it might be time to look into getting replacements.

I was looking to get some tyres for cycling on roads and occasionally on gravel/canal paths. but I'm now a bit overwhelmed with the amount of tyres available. Could anyone suggest what I should be looking for in a tyre?

Comment: Sorry but product recommendations are frowned upon here.

Comment: A way to rephrase this question so that it would stay useful (we frown on product recommendations because they tend to go "stale" very quickly) would be to put the question in terms of the criteria that would make one tire better than another – that won't change much over time. I've made some small edits to your question to do this. See if you like them – and never them if you don't!

Comment: Voting to keep open after the edit by @dlu

Comment: You have only a few parameters -- the basic tire size (apparently 20x1.75), the tire tread (relatively smooth for on-road, lugged for off-road), and whether the tire is "belted" or not to resist punctures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dahon [Vitesse D8](http://dahon.com/mainnav/folding-bikes/single-view/bike/vitesse_d8-1.html) site says it ships with

> KOMMUTER, 20" x 1.75"

tires.

Any tires of those dimensions will do the job.

The applications you mention suggest that a tire with a small amount of tread would be better than a slick (no tread) tire.

The mind boggling array of tires you see is because the suppliers are all trying to distinguish their products, when they all do pretty much the same job.

I recommend taking your bike to your [LBS](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/254/8273) and fit whatever tires they suggest, provided they have tread.

Comment: Uh, Andy you have a drive to up vote any question worth answering but you answered this and the question has no up votes.  :)

Comment: @Frisbee Yep, I just started the drive :-) But you're right, it looks better if I do as I say. PS I like the new screen name.

Comment: How did you know it was me?  I got a time out on this site for being rude and trying to make a fresh start.

Comment: The rep gives you away. Good to see you back, and good luck with the new efforts :-)